# Can't manage to store new user with Express & Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a user with express.
I am doing a POST request with all of the new user data at the param URL via Postman thru the following URL:

```
localhost:3000/users/register?first_name=1&last_name=1&email=1&password=123456&country=1&city=1&street=1&number=1
```

And I am getting this error on the console:

> There was an erorrError: Illegal arguments: undefined, string

In the model folder I created student.js, it is a user.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


const StudentSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address:
        {   country: String,
            city: String,
            street: String,
            number: Number
        },
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
});
StudentSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    this.updated_at = currentDate;
    if (!this.created_at)
        this.created_at = currentDate;

    next();
});
var Student = mongoose.model('Student', StudentSchema);
module.exports = Student;

module.exports.addStudent = function(newStudent, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newStudent.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(hash);
                **console.log("There was an erorr" + err);**
            }else {
                newStudent.password = hash;
                newStudent.save(callback);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

At the routes folder users router:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Student = require('../models/student');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
    var newStudent =new Student( {
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        address:
            {
                country: req.body.country,
                city: req.body.city,
                street: req.body.street,
                number: req.body.number
            }
    });

    Student.addStudent(newStudent, function(err,user) {
    if(err){
        res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed to register user'});
    } else {
        res.json({success: true, msg:'User registered'});
    }
    });
});

router.get('/newstudent', function(req, res) {
    res.render('newstudent', { title: 'Add student' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I markered the code line brakes with "**"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending the data in Postman with **query** parameters (which show up in the url), and expecting to extract the data in `req.body`.

You could change one of them (either in postman send request body, or in express extract the query params), but it's not recommended to send the sensitive data in like username/password in the URL because it's visible and less secure.

So you should change the way you send data in Postman to body like this:

[image]

Comment: @ModiNavon Glad I helped, please accept my answer if you think it solved it.